# jQuery posting JSON and decoding by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I've been searching all night in stackOverflow and Google to find a way to make my ajax work. I would like to post my data using json to a php form then decoding the json in php and processing them. After processing in php return back some data in json.

Below it my jquery codes which I'm using to send json to php .

```
        JSONobj = {
            firstname : "david", 
            email : "daivd@gmail.com"
        };

        var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Process.php",

                data: {info: JSON.stringify(JSONobj)},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                          alert(data.newName);
                        }
            });
```

but after parsing the json, my header is looks like this :

[image]

And what should I put in my PHP file ?

```
<?php    
$myJson =json_decode($_POST['info'], true);


    // modify the name and return the data in json back
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `JSON.stringfy()` method is use to convert array into json

so use `JSONobj=new array();`

```
 data: {info: JSONstr},
or 
 data:JSONstr;
```

in your php file use

```
$myjson->firstname;

 // than create a array using 

$newarray=array("firstname"=>$firstname,"lastname"=>$lastname);


echo json_encode($newarray)
```

Comment: my first problem is that the json parsing in jquery is not right. what should I do about that ?

Comment: when I'm sending the json , in my Header looks like this : info=%7B%22firstname%22%3A%22david%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22daivd%40gmail.com%22%7D

Comment: @user1725155 what are you getting in your php file?

Comment: @user1725155 this header is automatically created by browser..you do not need to care about this? use `$myjson->firstname;`

Comment: in my PHP , I'm getting : undefined index: info

Comment: @user1725155 use `data:JSONstr`;

Comment: I used : data:JSONstr , now my header looks clean : {"name":"david","email":"david@gmail.com"} ... but I still getting the same error for undefined index in php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17994/discussion-between-jhonraymos-and-user1725155)

Answer (score 0):

here's what I had to do:

```
$list = stripcslashes(utf8_encode(urldecode($_POST["list"])));
$obj = json_decode($list);
```

Then I saw the object when I did var_dump($obj);